# TypeError: highcharts is not a function

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a home page where a div named container is rendered by chart.
on the initial load, the chart is accessible by `pinnedChart = $("#container").highcharts()`

The div is refreshed as `$("#container")load("HighChart.jsp")` in a JS after which when i tried to fetch the chart using `pinnedChart = $("#container").highcharts(),`

it throws an `exception Error: TypeError: $(...).highcharts` is not a function.

In this page `HighChart.js` i have included `exporting.js` and `jquery.min.js`, while in the home page i have included `highstock.js` and `exporting.js`

Can some one help?

Comment: I know its an old Q, keep in mind it may happen due to more than one jQuery library on the page too.

Answer (score 2):

You should put java scripts in this order:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

This will surely work. Put Jquery file above highchart.js .

Answer (score 0):

This errors means that you have not included Highcharts/Highstock or you are trying to create chart before Highcharts/Highstock is loaded. Make sure you are using this methods after DOM is loaded:

```
$(function () { 
    /* put your code inside */ 
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

use `var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({`
instead of `$('#container').highcharts({`

or possible solution would be order of jquery and highchart script
it should be

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/drilldown.js"></script>
```